# Why can't user X write to directory despite having default:user:X:rwx ACL on the directory?

Tags: linux, file-permissions, access-control-list

As I understand it, this all looks good: `iammedemo` owns the directory, but `iammme` has `default:user:iamme:rwx`, so if anything, `iamme` should effectively be just as privileged as `iammedemo`, and be able to do anything in the directory:

```
[iamme@iamme-demo:~/IAMME]$ ls -last /tmp/badDir                                                  
total 28
 4 drwxr-xr-x+   2 iammedemo users  4096 Jun 22 00:50 .
24 drwxrwxrwt  220 iamme     users 20480 Jun 22 00:50 ..

[iamme@iamme-demo:~/IAMME]$ getfacl /tmp/badDir                                                   
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: tmp/badDir
# owner: iammedemo
# group: users
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:user:iamme:rwx
default:group::r-x
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x
```

But, I must be missing something:

```
[iamme@iamme-demo:~/IAMME]$ touch /tmp/badDir
touch: setting times of '/tmp/badDir': Permission denied                                       

[iamme@iamme-demo:~/IAMME]$ touch /tmp/badDir/foo                                                 
touch: cannot touch '/tmp/badDir/foo': Permission denied
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a symptom of having only given default ACLs on the directory, which provides ACLs for new files created by e.g. the owner of the directory. You *also* have to provide ACLs for the directory itself.

So you would need both

```
sudo setfacl -d -m "user:iammedemo:rwX" /tmp/badDir
sudo setfacl    -m "user:iammedemo:rwX" /tmp/badDir # Notice the missing -d
```